# How can I use tensorflow with Graphcore IPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, ipu

I want to test performance with graphcore IPU, but I don't know how to do with tensorflow. Someone can help me to do this?

Answer (score 7):

The Graphcore Poplar SDK includes two wheel files to install the Graphcore port for TensorFlow of either v1.15 or v2.1, for Python 3. You should install one of the two wheel files in your virtual environment, then you will need a few more steps to be able to run your model on the IPU device.

Depending on the application, some IPU-specific module imports need to be added to your program:

```
from tensorflow.python.ipu import utils, ipu_compiler, scopes, loops, ipu_infeed_queue, ipu_outfeed_queue
```

You will have to make sure to target the Graphcore IPU hardware by placing the TensorFlow graph on the IPU device and to remove any CPU/GPU/TPU-specific options you might have in your code. Then, you can use the custom IPU compiler to compile the TensorFlow graph:

```
with scopes.ipu_scope("/device:IPU:0"):
compiled = ipu_compiler.compile(training_loop)
```

Next step is to configure the IPU device: the basic configuration will consist in defining how many IPUs you want the model to run on. Assuming you only need one IPU:

```
config = utils.create_ipu_config()
config = utils.auto_select_ipus(config, [1])
utils.configure_ipu_system(config)
```

I’d recommend to read the relative reference guide [Targeting the IPU from TensorFlow](https://www.graphcore.ai/docs/targeting-the-ipu-from-tensorflow) as a primary introduction to the TensorFlow-to-Poplar API. You can also refer [to this document](https://www.graphcore.ai/docs/porting-tensorflow-models-to-the-ipu) as a practical guide for porting TensorFlow models on the IPU, with some guidance on best practices.